# How exactly is the movie a comedy?

Tags: genre, spring-breakers

Considering that both [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Breakers) and [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2101441/) have classified *Spring Breakers* as a *comedy-drama*, I'd like to know what exactly are the comic elements of the movie? The Britney Spears references? James Franco's (perhaps satirical) character? While weird and a li'l surreal, neither of them struck me as particularly funny. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many reviews are calling this a black comedy or dark comedy, which is comedy that makes light of a serious subject or a comedy with gloomy or disturbing elements. If this film was just a drama, it would be a serious depiction of four girls going on spring break and the tragedy that unfolded when they got mixed up with a gangster. Instead, there are pink ski masks, bikinis in court, lots of sex, references to Britney Spears, the mere existence of a drug dealer named Alien who shows up to bail the girls out of jail... The basic premise is ridiculous, and the way that violence is interspersed with this ridiculousness sets up an uncomfortable edge that seems to keep audiences talking about this movie. Mostly the characters are flat and the story is not that gripping, but the edge that Harmony Korinne keeps the audience on  - never knowing which direction it would go - seems to keep viewers engaged, whether they are engrossed or repelled.